# Use of colon in object assignment destructuring JavaScript

Tags: javascript, object, variable-assignment, destructuring

Working with React.js and React Router:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
  <Route {...rest} render={} />
)
```

`*{ component: Component, ...rest }*`

...rest is the use of spread syntax but what does `*component: Component*` do?

Comment: its creating an object. Its assigning the `Component` class imported from react to the key `component` in the newly created object. ie. `const newObj = { component: ComponentClass }`

Answer (score 30, accepted):

In ES6 this will assign the value to a new variable in this case named `foo`

```js
let obj = {
  name: 'Some Name',
  age: '42',
  gender: 'coder'
};
let { name: foo, ...rest } = obj;
console.log({foo, rest}) // { foo: 'Some Name', rest: { age: 42, gender: 'coder' } }
//
```

In this case, `name` will not be defined

See [assigning to new variable names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Assigning_to_new_variable_names)

Comment: is "foo" new value for key "name" OR new key name for "name" ? It's confusing.

Comment: @vikramvi here foo will be a variable containing the value "Some Name".

Comment: To further demonstrate the destructuring seen in this answer: The basic way to destructure in javascript is writing something like `let { name } = obj` which is the exact same thing as saying `let name = obj.name`.  But you could also choose to "rename" or pick a different name altogether for the new variable you're unpacking. In this example where you see something like `let { name: foo } = obj` that is doing the same exact thing as `let foo = obj.name`.