# Javascript const with curly braces which have 2 variable separated by colon

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm working on a react native project, I found a solution on internet to my problem but I don't understand one line from a function

```
componentDidUpdate(propsOld) { // line 1
    const { fill } = this.props;  // line 2
    const { fill:fillOld } = propsOld; // line 3

    if (fill !== fillOld) { // line 4
      Animated.timing(this.anim, { toValue:fill, duration:2000 // line 5 }).start();
    }
}
```

The line that I don't understand is the line 3:

`const { fill:fillOld } = propsOld;`

I understand the use of curly braces when there is a single variable or multiple variables seperated by comma ',',

Would anyone please explain to me the meaning when they are separated by colon ':' ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does ':' (colon) do in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/418799/what-does-colon-do-in-javascript)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use of Colon in object assignment destructuring Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51959013/use-of-colon-in-object-assignment-destructuring-javascript)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

basically that is renaming a variable when destructuring the object.

if you have an object like this:

```
const obj = {
    prop1: 'prop1',
    prop2: 'prop2',
    prop3: 'prop3',
}
```

and you want to get your variable `prop2`, you can do it like this:

```
const { prop2 } = obj;
```

but what if you already defined something with the same name? a block like this where you have `prop4` defined and you want to get that variable when destructuring?

```
const prop4 = 'something';
const obj = {
    prop1: 'prop1',
    prop2: 'prop2',
    prop3: 'prop3',
    prop4: 'else'
}
```

you can not do: `const { prop4 } = obj;` because `prop4` already exist and also it is a `const`

so basically you can rename it like this:

```
const { prop4: prop4duplicated } = obj;
```

so basically, on your code:

```
const { fill } = this.props;
const { fill:fillOld } = propsOld;
```

it is generating 2 variables, `fill` and `fillOld`, that is because `fill` already exists, then it is being renamed to `fillOld`

Answer (score 2):

Using a colon instead of a comma is that it created an alias for `fill`. So `fill` can now be referenced as `fillOld`. So if I wanted `bill` to be known as `fred` I would do `{ bill:fred }`