# Why do we have to specify the component prop differently than the other props in React Router DOM?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

When we are using the render prop, why do we have to specify the component prop as:

```
component: Component
```

All the other props use the regular destructured syntax:

```
exact
```

Is this specific to React Router DOM, or is this generally how you pass components in React? If so, why do we have to use this syntax?

Comment: Could you show an example with a little more _context_? Are you talking about https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/render-func? In that case the colon in `{ component: Component, ...rest }` is to effectively *rename* the `component` prop, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/51959013/3001761.

Comment: Thanks for that, that was the function I was referring to. Do you know why we have to rename the component prop?

Comment: Because it's being used in JSX. If you put `<component />` that is interpretered as a string, `React.createElement("component")`, whereas `<Component />` is interpreted as an *identifier*, `React.createElement(Component)`.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the reasoning here is due to the fact that React Router serves less as a parent component and more as a redirection library. Plugging your component into the *component* proceeds with a standard render where the query string, history and params are injected; However, this isn't the only option.

```
<Route path={this.props.match.url} exact render={() => 
   <Admin location={this.props.location} history={this.props.history}/>
}/>
```

The purpose of the Route is not to apply styling, props, or generic parent attributes, but rather to exclusively render the children with the injected props and path conditionals.

Comment: Thanks, do you know why we have to rename the component prop?